# Image Submission Form with Element Tags on Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to create a form on Wordpress where users can submit an image and then select different parts of the image, and a corresponding text field will appear on the side where the user will start typing the name of the element and predetermined Categories/Tags on my site will start being autosuggested. I am trying to create a list of all of the elements in the image by allowing the user to point to a part of the image and then type the element into a text field and the text field should autosuggest Categories/Tags that are already in my site.

I am looking at Gravity Forms to create the autosuggest text field but I am lost when it comes to the image tagging function. I am trying to use/integrate plugins to create this form function.

Any plugin suggestions? I appreciate the help. Thanks!